# Is it possible to find a particular value from Dropdown datasourse in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to check, particular value whether available in the loaded dropdown list data source, How to do it?

Here is the code which I tried and it works fine, but is there any simple way to find it?

```
if (ddlcountry.Items.Contains(ddlcountry.Items.FindByValue(drJob["Country"].ToString())) == true) 
{
  ddlcountry.SelectedValue = drJob["Country"].ToString(); //if available it assigns the value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following is much simpler:

```
ListItem item = ddlcountry.Items.FindByValue(drJob["Country"].ToString());
if(item != null)
    ddlcountry.SelectedValue  = item.Value;
```